# Alternative for "Structure" in EE3

Tags: structure, ee3

I've just started using Expression Engine 3, but it looks like my favourite "Structure" module isn't compatible with EE3. Does anyone know of a decent alternative that I can use?

Answer (score 4):

Check out TJ Draper's  [Construct](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/construct).

Comment: I'd second that recommendation. Structure (and I'm a big fan) takes over completely all of the URLs and page structure, etc. Construct is a nice approach which adds an independent layer to allow you to create page structure and present that visually in the Control Panel. The use of custom templates is far better too.

Answer (score 3):

This is an older question, but...for folks interested in this exact plugin for EE3, Structure has now been ported over.

https://eeharbor.com/structure